# How would a "blocking" strategy play differently in Ticket to Ride than other strategies?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Most of what I've read about Ticket to Ride focuses on "constructive" strategies of getting long destination routes and building them out for their large bonuses, including the longest route bonus. This allows one or more players to get over 200 points, but presumes a minimum of "blocking" from one player to another.

On the other hand, if players are inclined to block each other, then long destination routes might be a liability (because they can't be completed, and earn a *negative* bonus). In such a game, it seems like the trick is to take the two shortest destinations, build them "fast," and then spend the rest of the game blocking other people's routes. In such a game, scores might be closer to 100 than 200.

If only one player is playing "blocking," this strategy might not work, but it seems that if four or five (out of five) are playing this way, the game would play very differently than as discussed in the first paragraph. Just how would it play differently? Have I gotten at least some of the changes right in the previous paragraph>

Comment: What do you want to ask? If all players are playing differently, will the game play differently? Well, yeah. I don't see a point of this question as it is now.

Comment: @Deo: Modified the question to how would it play differently.

Comment: The (revised) question is actually very simple. I laid out a bunch of hypotheses in the second paragraph. Are they right or wrong? Is there anything that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it mostly right already, and certainly it will vary based on the people involved, but in my experience the jump from players focusing on their own agenda to being more interested in disrupting their opponents means shorter tickets are better, there is likely to be a lot of hoarding up cards until someone has enough to actually pursue a route, the longest train will be shorter than in the first scenario, etcetera. In my experience if one player pursues a blocking strategy while the other tries to do their own thing, the "do my own thing" player will win more often than not. That may change when you get into higher numbers of players.

Comment: This matches my experience as well generally.